# Azure Web App VNet Integration (Preview) vs external ASE

Tags: azure-web-app-service, app-service-environment

With the new VNet integration mode (currently in Preview), what are now the pros (and/or cons) of chosing external ASE instead ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) is often used to enable access from apps to a databases and web services running in your VNet. With VNet Integration, you don't need to expose a public endpoint for applications on your VM but can use the private non-internet routable addresses instead.

> There are some things that VNet Integration doesn't support including:
>
> mounting a drive
> AD integration
> NetBios
> private site access
> accessing resources across ExpressRoute
> accessing resources across Service Endpoints

If you have an External ASE, the **publish VIP is also the endpoint** that your ASE resolve to.
With VNet Integration, you don't need to expose a public endpoint for applications on your VM but can use the private non-internet routable addresses instead.

**App-assigned IP-based SSL addresses**: **Only** possible **with an External ASE** and when IP-based SSL is configured. With an External ASE, you can assign IP addresses to individual apps.

Public inbound IP address: Used for app traffic in an External ASE, and management traffic in both an External ASE and an ILB ASE.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info).